# Reading schema & metadata from a parquet file

Tags: node.js, parquet, apache-arrow

I am reading a third-party parquet file using **parquetjs-lite**

```
const parquet = require("parquetjs-lite"); 
:
reader = await parquet.ParquetReader.openFile(fileName);
cursor = reader.getCursor()
:
```

I am able to read the records (and rowCount) but how can I get the Schema and metadata info. Something like this from the doc (if I had created the Schema):

```
var schema = new parquet.ParquetSchema({
  name: { type: 'UTF8' },
  quantity: { type: 'INT64' },
  price: { type: 'DOUBLE' },
  date: { type: 'TIMESTAMP_MILLIS' },
  in_stock: { type: 'BOOLEAN' }
});
```

From the field-names of the third-party parquet.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you console log your cursor, you can get this type of info.

`console.log(cursor.schema)` will give you the types of each column in the parquet file.

You can use this to grab whatever info you would want i.e.

```
let exampleType = cursor.schema.schema.[COLUMN NAME].type
```